# What is a $k$-form on $[0,1]^k$ in Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

In Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds*, *differential forms* are loosely defined as follows (not in a way that uses vector bundles)

> ... a function $\omega$ with $\omega(p)\in\Lambda^k({\bf R}^n_p)$; such a function is called a $k$-form on ${\bf R}^n$, or simply a differential form.

In his book, Spivak only considers manifolds as subsets in ${\bf R}^n$. The way he defines integration on chains is confusing:
[image]
[image]

where $A$ is some subset of ${\bf R}^n$.

As I understand, the set $[0,1]^k$ is not even a manifold in ${\bf R}^k$. What does "a $k$-form on $[0,1]^k$" mean? (I can't find an explanation in the book.) Should it be a form on ${\bf R}^k$ *supported* on $[0,1]^k$?

Comment: Presumably this just means a restriction of a $k$-form $\omega$ on $\Bbb R^n$ to $[0, 1]^k$. This interpretation gives the correct behavior, anyway.

Comment: @Travis: When $k<n$, is $[0,1]^k$ "identified" in some way a subset of ${\bf R}^n$? Or shall one say it a a restriction of a $k$-form on ${\bf R}^k$ to $[0,1]^k$?

Comment: @Travis: When you say "restriction of *a* $k$-form $\omega$", do you mean that $\omega$ does not need to be zero outside $[0,1]^k$?

Comment: Up through the first displayed equation, Spivak is thinking of $\omega$ as a $k$-form on $[0, 1]^{k} \subset \mathbf{R}^{k}$; the first display defines the integral because at this point of the book we know how to integrate functions in the stated sense. The rest of the passage defines integration of a $k$-form (defined on some region $A \subset \mathbf{R}^{n}$) over a $k$-chain in $A$.

Comment: How this is done in Munkres, so I am assuming it is done the same here, is that $\omega$ is defined on an open set containing $[0,1]^n$.

Comment: @ConfusedMonkey: considering the time when Munkres published his book, I assume that Munkres was following Spivak's convention.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: I understand that in the first identity, the Riemann integral of $f$ is used to defined $\int_{[0,1]^k}\omega$. But I don't understand what a $k$-form on $[0,1]^k$ means. When you write $[0,1]^k\subset{\bf R}^n$ in your comment, do you intend to mean that $\omega$ is a  form on ${\bf R}^k$ supported on $[0,1]^k$? Similar issue  arises for the later "$\omega$ is a $k$-form on $A$" and $c^*\omega$ as a $k$-form on $[0,1]^k$.

Comment: Sorry, I made an inopportune typo: I mean, the restriction of $k$-form $\omega$ on $\Bbb R^k$, as in your question (and not one on $\Bbb R^n$), and then $[0, 1]^k$ is a bona fide subset of $\Bbb R^k$. The behavior of the extension of $\omega$ outside the cube is irrelevant, though depending on your setting you might require that the extension be continuous or $C^{\infty}$ or something else.